# Track multiple domains using Web & Mobile Analytics Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics, web-analytics-connector

I want to track my custom links that is present in my website in to Marketing cloud.
like how many times someone click on my facebook page link  from website like that
how we can do that?
Please Help me

Comment: What do you want to use this data for? Is it to drive outbound communications with contacts based on browsing behaviour? Is it just for reporting purposes? Do you use Google 360 or some other web analytics package?

Comment: Hello,thank you for update
I want to track information like who clicked on a button from website.then take that data to link with real subscriber

Comment: GA 360 would do some of what you want, if you have a licence for that or one of the other popular "premium" analytics packages can be integrated with SFMC. They tend to just identify an audience, rather than tell you contact X clicked Y times on this page. With SFMC's Collect code installation, you get the reporting and can manually export contacts visiting specific pages on your site to a Data Extension that you can then use to retarget contacts. It's a manual process, which is disappointing and won't get fixed any time soon. Salesforce will try to sell you Data Studio, which is overkill.

Comment: Bottom line is, there's not a lot out of the box using SFMC on its own. Normally you'd use a web analytics platform to do reporting on how many people visit a given page and use SFMC for execution of Marketing messages. The data driving SFMC's messaging normally comes from the analytics package, a DMP or some middleware.

Comment: Thank you you all these information